# Using Component without Import

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hi I would like to know if its possible to use a component without importing it again if it's already declared in AppModule. Since I have *10 or more pages/component to use* and it will be difficult to import each one and track.

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
],
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
],
providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And I would like to use **HomePage** without re-importing it. Since I have so many pages to deal it.

**other-page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginPage {
constructor(){ }
//Call HomePage here without having to import it again.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mention a class somewhere in code, it has to be imported, otherwise it's not recognized as that class which makes the code invalid or at least not do what you expect.

The imports at the top of the file are not related to Angular at all, they are TypeScript imports. The imports in `@NgModule()` are Angular imports and fullfill an entirely different purpose than TS imports.

Therefore adding components to `@NgModule()` doesn't make other imports obsolete.

Comment: Thanks so I would still need to always import those classes if they are called in that component. This could be a bit redundant but thanks to the clarification.

Comment: Yes, you always need a TS imports if you use a class' name in code, there is no way around that, and Angular needs component imports for associating components with a module.

Comment: ya but the biggest issue with typescript import is you have to know what you exactly need. for example you cannot dynamically import a component on a click event , if you have million modules define you have to write million lines of imports.. i used to love angular now am getting back to dojo and other flexible javascript frameworks for this reason.

Comment: It's a different way of developing software, more like with Java. For bigger applications this is considered an advantage (static code checking, better tree-shaking, ...). If you love JavaScript, I can imagine that this is not compelling to you.

Answer (score 2):

To use the `Comonent` in your source code (ts-file), you need to `import` it, so that `TypeScript` recognizes it.
If you only want to use it in the `Template`, it needs to be recognized only by the `Angular` framework and no import is needed.

To let `Angular` know about your `Component`, you need to `declare` it in a `NgModule`. Every `Component` inside this `NgModule` will then know your `Component`.
To let other `NgModule`s know your `Component`, you need to `export` it from the declaring `NgModule` and `import` that `NgModule` in the other `NgModule`s.